# Maven - Can't run .jar file due to NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, mqtt, paho

I´m trying to run a .jar (mvn install) but i get the following error:

[image: error-img]

These are my dependencies:

[image: dependencies-img]

And my ClassPath-file:

[image: cp-img]

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and format it.  These images are really hard to read (and impossible for people using screen readers)

Comment: 1. Have you put all the dependencies into your POM? 2. How did you try to run it? Inside the IDE? Or just on command line?

Comment: I’ve got all dependencies in my POM. It works if I run the main class in IntelliJ. If I build a .jar it gave me the error. I tried to run the jar in IntelliJ and in Terminal.